# How to control AV Player from different controllers

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, avplayer

I have 2 ViewControllers and each one has a couple of buttons to play and stop audio. This audio has been deployed in a separate model to be able to access from the two ViewControllers, but I  don't know if that's the right way...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import "AudioController.h"

@interface NowViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) AudioController *AudioModel;

- (IBAction)PauseButton:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayButton:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

```
#import "NowViewController.h"

@interface NowViewController ()

@end

@implementation NowViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.AudioModel = [[AudioController alloc] init];

}

- (IBAction)PlayButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.AudioModel PlayAudio];

}

- (IBAction)PauseButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.AudioModel PauseAudio];
}

@end
```

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AudioController.h"

@interface CategoriesViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) AudioController *AudioModel;

- (IBAction)PauseButton:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayButton:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

```
#import "NowViewController.h"

@interface NowViewController ()

@end

@implementation NowViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.AudioModel = [[AudioController alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)PlayButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.AudioModel PlayAudio];
}

- (IBAction)PauseButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.AudioModel PauseAudio];
}

@end
```

The problem I have is that if I play the audio from one page and navigate to the other one, then I can't stop the audio. As the same way, I can't play/pause from the multitask. Here's the code of the AudioModel:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>   
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AudioController : NSObject{

    AVPlayer *Player;
}

- (void)PlayAudio;
- (void)PauseAudio;

@end
```

```
#import "AudioController.h"

@implementation AudioController

- (void)PlayAudio {
    Player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [Player play];
}

- (void)PauseAudio {

    [Player pause];
}

NSString *url = @"http://jo.my/xxx";

@end
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this design, but from the way you've written the AVPlayer code it doesn't look like it would work.

Comment: It's like every time I chage the view it enabled a new session, I don't know what could be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating two different instances of `AudioController` class in the `viewDidLoad`method of each controller.

You can solve your problem in several ways. For example, transforming the `AudioController` class in a singleton.

Comment: It works, but I can't control the player with physical controls or control center buttons. Thanks!!